# add requestmapping annotation on bean definition with annotation

Tags: spring, spring-annotations

I'm able to define bean with `@Component` and add `@Requestmapping` on that, But I have to define my bean with `@Bean` because i have multiple beans of the same class. Each bean should have it's own URL.
I have tried to add `@Requestmapping` on my method behind `@Bean` but it wasn't allowed.
So how can i add `@Requestmapping` on `@Bean`?
Here is my Code:

```
@Bean("documentSearchServiceImpl")
public SearchServiceImpl documentSearchService(@Autowired @Qualifier("documentSearchEngine") SearchEngine searchEngine) {
 return new SearchServiceImpl(searchEngine); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead using @Bean use

> @Controller

Comment: Look at my code:
@Bean("documentSearchServiceImpl")
public SearchServiceImpl documentSearchService(@Autowired @Qualifier("documentSearchEngine") SearchEngine searchEngine) {
 return new SearchServiceImpl(searchEngine);
}
So as you said i`ve changed @Bean to @Controller
The result is a compile error:
The annotation @Controller is disallowed for this location